# jqueryUi autocomplete - custom data and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HfNk9/13/

I am looking to this example [jqueryUi autocomplete - custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/custom-data.html).

Let's suppose the object projects is different and it looks like this:

```
project = [
    {
        name: 'bar',
        value: 'foo',
        imgage: 'img.png'
    }
]
```

If I set `source = project` the autocomplete refers to `project.value` and not `project.name`.
How should I change this behaviour?

---

```
var autocomplete = function(element, data) {
    var fixtures = [
        {
        avatar: "http://www.placekitten.com/20/20",
        name: 'aaaaaaaaa',
        value: 'bbbbbbbbb'}
    ];

    element.autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(fixtures, function(value) {
                return matcher.test(value.name);
            }));
        },
        create: function() {
            console.log(fixtures)
            element.val(fixtures.name);
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            element.val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            element.val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append('<a><img src="' + item.avatar + '" />' + item.name + '<br></a>')
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
};

autocomplete($('#auto'));
```

My full code: http://jsfiddle.net/HfNk9/13/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to filter on a different property than the autocomplete widget searches on by default (as you've noticed it's `name` or `value` when using a source array with objects).

You can use a function instead of an array as the source and perform your own filtering that way:

```
element.autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response($.grep(fixtures, function(value) {
            return matcher.test(value.name);
        }));
    },
    create: function() {
        console.log(fixtures)
        element.val(fixtures.name);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        element.val(ui.item.name);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        element.val(ui.item.name);
        return false;
    }
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<li></li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<a><img src="' + item.avatar + '" />' + item.name + '<br></a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QzJzW/

Comment: Another thing, the "a" tag in the render is necessary, without it things like focus method or others will fail (no ui.item set).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `select` property:

```
$("...").autocomplete({
    source: ...,
    select: function( event, ui ) { //when an item is selected
        //use the ui.item object
        alert(ui.item.name)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try but it does not work. I posted my full code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the source code to the page you've linked to. If you want to use the value of `name` instead of `value` then you would do something like this:

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#input" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#input" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
    }
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try but it does not work. I posted my full code.